# C++ - Passing Pointer Into Function

Tags: c++, pointers

I keep on receiving odd unexpected values for my bool `testValue`. I keep receiving random numbers as I believe it is trying to access another region of memory. I predict it is how my code is setup within my `testNumber()` function, but I am unsure of how to solve it. This is my logic.

I have set `ok` to true. Now I assign the memory address of `ok` to `pOk`.

```
void TextBox::lengthTest(bool *pOk, int length) {
  bool ok;

  if (length < MAX_LENGTH) {
    ok = true;
    pOk = &ok;
  } else {
    ok = false;
    pOk = &ok;
  }
}

bool lengthTestBool = lengthTest(*pOk, length);
cout << lengthTestBool <<;
```

output:

```
85
```

Comment: Woah, is this actually compiling?

Comment: No it is not compiling. The function is void and I don't believe that `*pOk` at the call site is in fact a pointer to `bool`. It would help if you posted the real code. Use copy/paste. And if you get odd results, don't make us guess what those results are. Include them in your question.

Comment: Well those last two lines should not compile for a variety of reasons (and in fact they do not in `g++`).

Comment: @Adam Mihalcin See the Homework tag description. It is being removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding of how one uses pointers to implement reference semantics. You want to change thing that is *pointed to* by the pointer:

```
*pOK = ok;
```

However, C++ actually supports references semantics natively through *reference types*, which may be preferable:

```
void testNumber(bool & OK, int n)
{
    OK = true;
    // ... 
}
```

Even better, though, is to simply *return* a bool:

```
bool testNumber(int n) { /* ... */ }

if (testNumber(x)) //... etc.
```

Comment: I want to try to return not return any value. It makes sense that I want to change what *pOk is pointing to. So I modified the contents of my IF statement to { *pOk = false; } but my program crashes when I run.

Comment: @cupcake_lover Until you can post the real code you are wasting our time. There's no point in trying to debug made up code. Use CTRL+C, CTRL+V and the clipboard.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry, I added my real code. I used fake code because I wanted to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @cupcake_lover Nope, that's still not it. Your function is `void` and yet you assign its return value to `lengthTestBool`. The way to make it clear is to post real code. But if the only remaining error in the Q is the return value then you can accept Kerrek's answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can't post my *real* code online. I'm doing an assignment, and my professor will deduct marks if he finds out I've gone to non-school source for help. That is why I'm trying to make my code as un-related to the assignment as possible by modifying the variable names and such. Thank you for your help though. I think I now understand my problem. :) Part of the requirements for the assignment is to use a pointer to return a value while leaving the function void.

Comment: @cupcake_lover In future please post real code and add the homework tag when you ask the question. If you want to modify the code before you post, then for crying out loud, make sure it compiles and behaves as you describe. To progress in the world of programming you need to be precise.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize that there was a homework tag. I will modify this Q to include that.

Comment: @cupcake_lover: If you had spent any amount of time on StackOverflow, you would have noticed how we tend to be very insistent that you mark homework as such. Do take a look around and get a feel for how this site works; read the FAQ, and see what other questions look like and what reactions they trigger.